# Processing 3.3 64 bit Android Mode : Error from inside the Android tools, check the console

Tags: android, processing, device

I followed this tutorial http://android.processing.org/tutorials/getting_started/index.html

I have tried to run my Processing code on my Android device.
My device is successfully detected by Processing.
But When I tried to run my code on my device, existed this error:

```
Error from inside the Android tools, check the console.

[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Tianran\AppData\Local\Temp\android265366583508353702sketch\bin
 [echo] org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Tianran\AppData\Local\Temp\android265366583508353702sketch\build.xml:81: Cannot find C:\Users\Tianran\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\ant\build.xml imported from C:\Users\Tianran\AppData\Local\Temp\android265366583508353702sketch\build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds
```

My OS is Windows 10 64bit This was my first time to try to run Processing code on Android device and failed.

I have tried different SDK target.(from API 15 to 25). My device is HONOR 7(Android Version 6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a dialog, let me choose 1, to download android SDK directly. or 2, choose the folder for Android SDK.
I have chosen the 2, then the problem occurred.

So I have downloaded the Android SDK for Processing
(instead of choosing the existing folder address from Android SDK(I deleted the saved address in preferences.txt) )
and solved this problem.